# Removing duplicate ID's in a single cell

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have a data table in R with multiple columns, where one column has IDs separated by " // ". Some are duplicates, I need to remove the duplicates and keep the unique IDs. So rows 1, 2, 5 in columns 3 need to look like rows 1, 2, 5 in column 1 in the example below. The number of IDs separated by " // " is at least 2.

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(letter = LETTERS[1:5], number = 1:5, id = paste(LETTERS[1:5], c(LETTERS[1:2], LETTERS[1:2], LETTERS[5]), sep = " // "))
```

Comment: What do you intend for rows 3 and 4? Stay the same?

Comment: Can you provide a better example including the desired output? Also what do you mean "# of IDs sep by // is >= 2"? Include this case as well, describe what should happen.

Comment: Perhaps something involving `sapply(strsplit(d$id, "[ /]+"), unique)`.

Comment: Rows 3/4 stay the same. @r2evans

Comment: You can have A // A // A or A // A but both need to be replaced by A. @AdamO

Comment: Perhaps you could provide guidance on your expectations for rows 3 and 4 (ref: my first comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(letter = LETTERS[1:5], number = 1:5, id = paste(LETTERS[1:5], c(LETTERS[1:2], LETTERS[1:2], LETTERS[5]), sep = " // "))

# Split id by one or more / surrounded with spaces
# And calculate how many unique values there are
d[, id2 := ifelse(length(unique(unlist(strsplit(id, " (/)\\1+ ")))) == 1, 
                         letter, 
                         id), 
   1:nrow(d)]
```

**Result:**

```
   letter number     id    id2
1:      A      1 A // A      A
2:      B      2 B // B      B
3:      C      3 C // A C // A
4:      D      4 D // B D // B
5:      E      5 E // E      E
```

Comment: This relies on `$letter` being already defined, right? I suggest that that column was provided primarily as after-the-fact reference.

Comment: LETTERS is predefined in R @r2evans

Comment: @abbas786, true, but that has nothing to do with this. Notice two things: (1) `letter` is referring to the *column*, which should be clear given that lower-case `letter` is producing upper-case values; and (2) it is singular `letter`, not `letters` or `LETTERS`.

Comment: I see what you meant. Let me explain, `$letter` is defined by `LETTERS` which is a predefined object of the alphabet in R. @r2evans

Comment: *No need to explain* the existence of `letters` and `LETTERS`. The question was incomplete so I made an assumption that the MWE was contrived with the *actual answer* in the first column and the *known data* in the third column. If the *actual answer* is in the data all along, I'm confused, but it isn't the first time I'm made assumption mistakes like this. You know your data, so I'm glad this works for you.

Comment: This is basically a loop per row. While each operation is very expensive. You could at least avoid rexeg and do something like `strsplit(id, " // ", fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
d[, flag := substr(id, 1, 1) == substr(id, 6, 6)]
d[flag == T, id := substr(id, 1, 1)]
d[, flag := NULL]
d
```

You'll get your desired output:-

```
        letter number id
1:      A      1      A
2:      B      2      B
3:      C      3 C // A
4:      D      4 D // B
5:      E      5      E
```

**Updated**

Here is a one line solution for this problem:-

```
d[substr(id, 1, 1) == substr(id, 6, 6), id := substr(id, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: If the ids are always of length one, this is much better answer than the accepted one, as it is vectorized. Though, you could significantly shorten it without creating `flag` at all, e.g., just `d[substr(id, 1, 1) == substr(id, 6, 6), id := letter]` should do.

Comment: Thanks for an advice @DavidArenburg. But, I guess it should be this way if I remove creating `flag` `d[substr(id, 1, 1) == substr(id, 6, 6), id := substr(id, 1, 1)]`.